# Select2 4.0 placeholder undefined

Tags: jquery-select2-4

Please, help.

html:

```
<select id="select-client" class="form-control" style="width: 350px;"></select>
```

js:

```
$("#select-client").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: _app.url + "finduser",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            return {
                q: params.term
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    templateResult: formatClientRepo,
    templateSelection: formatClientRepoSelection,
    placeholder: "Enter user name"
});
```

And as result I've received this: http://prntscr.com/76jxvi
I found many variants, such as empty option in select, or write placeholder in **select**, but nothing.

Comment: Have you checked the console?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: You may be running into undefined behaviour, you're missing the blank `<option></option>` that Select2 uses for the placeholder.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xqhp0z0x/1/

Comment: The fiddle works fine with the placholder for me (FF 38.0, Chromium 41) - are you using IE <10 or something?

Comment: So, I've found that the "placeholder" is located in `repo.text` in `formatClientRepoSelection` function. And no Select2 4.0 no needed in empty `option` tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/xqhp0z0x/1/

in this example if we delete `|| repo.text` from `formatRepoSelection` it will not work. Because the `repo.text` is placeholder.

P.S. select2 4.0 do not need to empty `option` tag for `placeholder` working

Comment: Your last line is incorrect, as I mentioned before not including a blank `<option>` in a single select while expecting the placeholder to be displayed **is undefined behaviour**.

Comment: but in fiddle we don't have the blank `<option>` and all works.

Comment: Works like a charme. They should update this in the select2 docs.